# Bankera GitHub script to redeem commissions - How does it works?

Tags: blockchain

First of all, I have contacted Bankera and no help is offered because this is an open source script. I have then contacted their community in their live chat and no one has any clues on how this script works(but would love to know) this is why I turned to Stack Overflow to get some help, this post will help a lot of users.
I have to redeem commissions on some of my tokens, the problem is that I need to run this script to get them:
https://github.com/Bankera-token/BNK-ETH-Contract

**As it says at the top:**
*The Contract has to have an Ethereum address in order to deposit a reward. Once the reward is set up for the weekly round, the claim amount will be proportionally divided among round token holders. For example, Jack, John and Bob have 1, 2 and 2 tokens respectively. If 100 ethers are placed in the round as a reward, Jack, John and Bob can claim 20, 40, 40 ethers respectively through the smart contract.*

I ran the first 2 commands and it created a node_module folder with all the dependencies required.

```
start init.sh
npm i
```

I then ran this command:

```
start runrpc.sh
start run.sh
```

All I see is a black screen for 1/2 second and disappear.

Where in this script shall I set my address to redeem the commission?

And also how can I run the functions from this script? I have a PHP background but I am zero with Bash and Blockchain.

I am on windows 10.

I have looked everywhere for help, no one in the community knows how this works

Thank you.

Comment: I think the linked Github is actually the token contract, so you don't have to run that. You can find the `Contract ABI` in the [Bankera ERC20 Contract here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc80c5e40220172b36adee2c951f26f2a577810c5#code). [Here's a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R-N76ijt4w&feature=youtu.be) which shows how you can call the contract method `claimReward` from MEW. It's in italian but you should be able to follow the steps done in MEW

Comment: You are a king! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome! :)